# Entity framework update table based on the column type getting from function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Hi all I am having a table data displayed in grid which is having nearly 15 columns, so on click of each td I will display a modal so that user can update and save the data. I am trying to write a common function so that it takes ColumnName and ColumnValue as parameters which will be called by MVC view

```
[HttpPost]
Public JsonResult UpDateData(string ColumnName, string ColumnValue, int id)
{
    var dbData = context.Table.Where(i=>i.Pid == id).FirstOrDefault();
    Table t = new Table();
    t = dbData;
    t.SomeColumnName = ColumnValue; // Here I need a generic way to handle so that it should match the passed columnname, so that if I edit and pass another value it should accept
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using reflection

```
[HttpPost]
Public JsonResult UpDateData(string ColumnName, string ColumnValue, int id)
{
    var dbData = context.Table.Where(i=>i.Pid == id).FirstOrDefault();

    var oType = dbData .GetType();
    var prop = oType.GetProperty(ColumnName);
    object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(ColumnValue, 
    prop.PropertyType);
    prop.SetValue(dbData , convertedValue); //set the value
}
```